# How to maintain the aspect ratio of a Button's BackgroundDrawable

Tags: android, drawable, aspect-ratio

When I use Button.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable), the drawable object gets stretched instead of having its aspect ratio maintained.  How can I maintain the aspect ratio?  I can't use an ImageButton because I also need the ability to write text on the button.  FWIW, the image is a BitmapDrawable loaded from a file.

Edit: I would like for the button to be resized to fit the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type of background will the buttons have?  Is it an image of something? Or just a custom border and color scheme and what not?

If it is just a custom button look, I would look into using 9-patch drawables.  They will allow you to make buttons of all different shapes and sizes and have the corners of your buttons maintain the proper sizing.

Comment: The background is an arbitrary image selected by a user.

Comment: what effect are you aiming for if the image is not the same dimensions as the button?  Should it fill whichever is smaller, width or height, and then leave blank space around the other dimension?

Comment: It should stretch the Button to fit the image.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ohh I see.  Well you could get the bitmap, check its width and height, and then set the width and height of the button to match those

Comment: That is a simple and direct solution that I never would have thought of.  :-)  Thank you.